# java.lang.VerifyError: processing.video.MovieMaker in processing 1.5.1

Tags: android, video, processing

i'm using processing 1.5.1 library to create video from list of PImage and here is the link for the library http://www.processing.org/ but when i use the Movie Maker class with android i keep getting this error java.lang.VerifyError: processing.video.MovieMaker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a problem with Java for processing 1.5.1 try to use newer version Processing 2.1.1 works good with the class for me. If you have to use Processing 1.5.1 you can make a connection between 2.1.1 and 1.5.1 using javascript

Comment: how  can i make this connection in  javascript in android??